# PHP Script To Run in background of application (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I currently have a stock control system, that is all working fine. (In PHP & MYSQL)

What I've done, is set up a "minimum_on_hand" column on the database, stating the minimum amount of that particular stock item, before more needs to be ordered.

As soon as one single item reaches the lowest the amount that the (made up) company can operate with, I want it to throw an alert, and then iterate through the database seeing which ever stock items are also low..and near their minimum_on_hand amount.

And then, give a list to the user of items running low for them to compile an order

The only current idea I have, is to call a script every time a new page is loaded, but this will cause hundreds of hits on the database.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: A cronjob might give you a solution

Comment: You can create a trigger, event or a cron.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the system cronjobs execute the script every XXX minutes.
2. cache the last time of the script executed. before the next executing, check the last executed time.

> ```
> if(time() - $last < XXX){
>     return;
> }else{
>     //what you want to do 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to cron job that people recommend, I suggest this alternative, if cron is not available for some reason:

Put an abscure image tag, 1x1 px with src attribute pointing to the script that needs to run in the background `<img src="/scripts/run-some-background-tasks.php" />` on the page that alters # of items in stock (like an "order successfully completed" page for instance). That is of course if you don't care if somebody will see a URL to that background script.